# Hide Background Image with Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey

I've been looking into this for hours, and I can't figure it out, so I'll just ask.

I need to hide a background image from a page using Greasemonkey. It's supposed to work, but for some reason it's not working.

**Greasemonkey script:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        123
// @namespace   123
// @include     https://www.somesite.org/some-site-page.php
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$('a').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('background-image')=='url("https://www.somesite.org/img/icon/some-background-image-photo.png")'){
       $(this).parent().remove();
   }
```

**Background image code:**

```
.profile_view_img_6915039 {
    background-image: url('https://www.somesite.org/img/icon/some-background-image-photo.png');
}
```

**Note:** I can't use the .profile_view_img_### class to hide it, because that number changes on every refresh, and I need it to work between refreshes. So I must use that image URL as the selector, and then hide it somehow.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you could select it with `a[class^="profile_view_img_"]`.

Comment: Problem is, on the same page there are other images that start with the same class - profile_view_img - and I don't want to hide them all. I just want to hide the one image. Can I expand that to also include the image url specifically?